# Symfony2 caching

Tags: caching, symfony

What can I do to redeclare Contoroller function renderView function (without hardcoding)?

How can I lookup twig cache (I think it's should be lookup function in HttpCache class , but it's says Fatal error: Call to a member function isNotModified() when I try redefine it ), and write it into memcache?

Are there native memcache settings working with twig in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1):

`isNotModified` is a method on `HttpFoundation\Response` that takes a `HttpFoundation\Request` object and checks the lastModified and ETags on a Request. You should not use `HttpCache` directly but look at `Response` and `Request` classes to see their API. Also there is a Symfony dokumentation [click here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html)